# How could I get access to the Audit log for non-admin users?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm building a Web Part for SharePoint 2010 and I've found out that non-admin users are getting `Access Denied` error message when I execute the following code (the error is thrown in the last line):

```
SPAuditQuery wssQuery = new SPAuditQuery(web.Site);
wssQuery.RestrictToUser(web.CurrentUser.ID);
wssQuery.AddEventRestriction(SPAuditEventType.View);
wssQuery.RestrictToList(SPContext.Current.List);

SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol;
auditCol = web.Site.Audit.GetEntries(wssQuery);
```

How can I let non-admin users access this log from the web part? Because I need to filter by nono-admin users, even if a non-admin user is logged in at that moment.

Comment: did you tried putting your code inside RunWithElevatedPreviledges ?

Comment: No, without doing anything in advance...do you think it might work?

Comment: Well, this turned out to be the best solution for this issue, please post it as a solution yourself if you want.

Answer (score 1):

.NET Reflector tells me that the `SPAuditEntryCollection GetEntries(SPAuditQuery query)` method performs the following check before it attempt to retrieve data:

```
if (!this.m_Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin)
{
    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
}
```

You can consider:

1. querying the `dbo.AuditData` table directly (*accessing SharePoint database directly is generally discouraged, but you'll read-only access, so it shouldn't cause any problems*),
2. creating a custom SharePoint Web service - this should be simple, because all it needs to do is execute the `GetEntries` method and return the result.

Comment: That sounds reasonable...I'll try to find a better solution, but meanwhile I think I'll try either of these 2. Thanks.